# Migrated to new SwiftUI App protocol and my FCM notifications stopped working

Tags: swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging

I migrated my app to use the new SwiftUI App protocol and get away with UIKit lifecycle.

Has anyone managed to get Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications to work with the new #SwiftUI app lifecycle? Get registration token but don't receive any messages. All we are doing is switching `@main` to our new App view, and using the app delegate adapter.

Comment: Have you tried `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,  withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)`?